# Ruby ||= equivalent in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ruby

I've been learning ruby as of late and am basically in love with the ||= feature as it would make writing lazy getters much easier in Objective C.

Currently I write getters such as:

```
- (NSArray *)myArray {
  if (!_myArray) {
    _myArray = [NSArray array];
  }
  return _myArray
}
```

Unless im missing something with the ||= I would be able to write the previous code in Ruby using:

```
- (NSArray *)myArray {
  return _myArray ||= [NSArray array];
}
```

Thats obviously much cleaner. Is there anything at all in the Objective-C language/runtime that would enable you to do this?

Also, the following is a one line ternary for getters, im not sure if its as effective as the tried and true method posted above (first snippet). Can someone tell me if theres anything wrong with doing:

```
- (NSArray *)myArray {
  return _myArray = _myArray ? _myArray : [NSArray array];
}
```

Comment: Though I do not know Objective C, wouldn't you want to have `_myArray = [NSArray array];` in a class Constructor or initialize method? Again, just a potential suggestion by a guy who doesn't know Objective C :p

Comment: Note that all of the above are incorrect if you care about thread-safety.

Comment: Multithreading introduces the possibility that Thread A could call the setter, fail the non-nil test, and then be pre-empted by Thread B, which also calls the setter and fails the non-nil test. Both threads have decided to create a new -- separate -- `NSArray` and store it in `_myArray`; hilarity ensues.

Answer (score 12):

The last snippet has the same effect as the first one you posted.

As an improvement, while there's no operator like `||=` in Objective-C, you can omit the second parameter of a ternary if operator and do

```
return _myArray = _myArray ?: [NSArray array];
```

which is exactly equivalent to

```
return _myArray = _myArray ? _myArray : [NSArray array];
```

This is a language extension supported by modern versions of both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1BinaryConditionalOperator.html).

Bonus: if you want to save some more keystrokes, you can do

```
- (NSArray *)myArray {
    return _myArray = _myArray ?: @[];
}
```

---

As a side note, skipping the middle operand can also have some benefit.

For instance in this case

```
id x = [self someMethod] ? [self someMethod] : [self anotherMethod];
```

if `someMethod` evaluates to `true` it will be called twice, whereas doing

```
id x = [self someMethod] ?: [self anotherMethod];
```

it will only be called once.

Comment: I like this a lot, provides validation of my ternary and improves upon it. Good stuff. Very sad theres no ||= though.

Comment: Indeed, but consider that Objective-C is a much older language than ruby. Moreover, being such a thin layer over the original C, I agree with the design choice of not introducing any "extraneous" operator to the language.

Answer (score 3):

There's no literal equivalent, unless you want to [hack on Clang](http://www.stuartcarnie.com/2012/06/llvm-clang-hacking-part-3.html). The `||` logical operator, while it short-circuits, doesn't evaluate to its operands. A macro, using the ternary conditional, will get you close:

```
#define NON_NIL(o, p) ((o) ? (o) : (p))

- (NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
    return _myArray = NON_NIL(_myArray, [NSMutableArray array]);
}
```

because assignment in C sort of acts like an expression and evaluates to the assigned value.

You could actually make an `OR_ASSIGN()` macro, too, but I'm going to leave that as an exercise for the utterly deranged reader.

Perhaps equally deranged would be a function:

```
id lazySet(id *obj; id(^valBlock)(void))
{
    if( !(*obj) ){
        *obj = valBlock();
    }
    return *obj;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
    return lazySet(&_myArray, ^{return [NSMutableArray array]});
}
```

but that's just getting ridiculous.

Comment: fascinating but scary and kind of ugly to see. Anyway I just learned a new word: deranged. I'm surely going to abuse of it over the next few days. Thanks for the English lesson.

Comment: Oh and you can improve the first macro using the "missing-middle" `?:` operator

Comment: My pleasure, @Gabriele! (Thanks for pointing that out. I have a slight, perhaps-irrational preference for not leaving out the middle operand.)

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, even though I believe is a safe construct and it can save a method call sometimes (see my answer).

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: That's true, avoiding double-evaluation can be important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Josh, its fun to geek out about obscurities and finding ways to reduce key strokes.

Comment: Sure thing, @Peter. It certainly is fun.