# Is it possible to use the ternary operator in lazy instantiation of a getter in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have a property called deck of class Deck,

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) Deck *deck;
```

I can lazily instantiate it as follows,

```
    - (Deck *)deck{
      if(!_deck) _deck = [[Deck alloc] init];
      return _deck;
    }
```

However is it possible to lazily instantiate it using a C ternary operator as follows?

```
    - (Deck *)deck{
     return _deck ? _deck:[[Deck alloc] init];  
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can. That you write absolutely fine.

Comment: That was fast! Thank you.

Comment: @TapasPal, look again. This code will *always* create a new `Deck` as `_deck` isn't *ever* set (unless it's set elsewhere, which perhaps defeats purpose of a *lazy* getter). This probably isn't the desired behavior of this method.

Comment: @JRG-Developer, thanx a lot, I just checked that the ternary operator will work but I missed that what is happening. thanx once again please ignore my above comment. `user2998842` please check `JRG-Developer` answer.

Comment: Closely related/same answer: [Ruby ||= equivalent in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19602374)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would actually prefer your initial version, because it is easily readable.

If you want to get fancy and write less code, you can use the [Conditionals with Omitted Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html), which is a GCC extension
also understood by Clang:

```
- (Deck *)deck{
    return _deck ? : (_deck = [[Deck alloc] init]);
}
```

`_deck` is evaluated only once, and only assigned to if it was `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this

```
- (Deck *)deck {
     _deck = _deck ? _deck : [[Deck alloc] init];
     return _deck;
}
```

If you use your proposed lazy getter, `_deck` won't ever be set unless it's done elsewhere... that is, you never actually set `_deck` in your second method. Instead, you will get a new `Deck` each time.

Comment: Oh I see that now. Thank you for your fast and accurate reply.